# How do i overwrite the default Backbone Model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I want to overwrite the default Backbone Model variable (Backbone.Model) to use my own custom validation methods (isValid, validate) and to add some properties.

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model, {
    isValid: function() { // custom function },
    validate: function() { // custom logic }
});

var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   // this adds for example properties to my modified Backbone model.
});
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work... when I load the "wrapper, extending"-module with requirejs and create a new Model instance and than call validate. It says that it doesn't know any validate function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to extend `Backbone.Model.prototype` rather then `Backbone.Model` itself as all the methods are prototype methods of the constructor function rather then properties on the model. Though it might be better idea to create a custom BaseModel that will extend the Backbone.Model and implement your custom logic so that if backbone gets updated etc. you will avoid possible conflicts even if in this case they are rather unlikely it's still considered a better practice to extend base Backbone classes rather then to modify them.

Comment: I also thought about this idea. This would be a similar approach how Backbone.marionette takes. However I would prefer to continue the use of Backbone.Model. Could you give me a code snippet about the prototype extention?

Comment: Here are some good examples how to extend core backbone functionality http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#mixins

Comment: hope you got to it by now but just in case just replace `_.extend(Backbone.Model, {` with `_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {` voila!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do custom Models for the project instead of "overwrite" that is not OOP. (at the end of the way could be the same but if we try to emulate OOP I feel that is more easy to understand).

Check my example, I define YourAbstractModel that it is the kind of extension of the Backbone.Model, then all of my Models extend that abstract Model instead of the Backbone Model.

```
var YourProject = {};
YourProject.YourAbstractModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    customProperty1 : null, 
    customProperty2 : null, 
    isValid : function(){ },    
    specificUtility : function(){ } 
});

var YourModel1 = YourProject.YourAbstractModel.extend({
    customProperty1 : 'aaaaa'
});
var YourModel2 = YourProject.YourAbstractModel.extend({
    customProperty1 : 'bbbbb'
});

console.log( new YourModel1().customProperty1 );
console.log( new YourModel2().customProperty1 );
```

My way is also flexible to have more than one abstract Model, does not conflict with updates of Backbone and I feel is more close to inheritable process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Backbone.Validation plugin by thedersen 
https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation

Its pretty helpful and easy to use. You can also bind your view to the model, so that your view has your custom-error attribute for the specific model property which failed validation.